# Generate a footnote only if none already generated on this page for a given label

Tags: macros, footnotes, automation

My document frequently refers to C library functions. I have written a command to semantically wrap them.

```
\newcommand{\cfunc}[2]
{
    \texttt{#2}
    \footnote{See \texttt{man #1 #2}.}
    \index{#2}
}

The \cfunc{3}{malloc} function allocates memory...
```

This does the job nicely except that if the same function is mentioned multiple times on one page, I get multiple footnotes. I want to use the same `\cfunc` wrapper at each mention so that the index is correct, but I want to only generate the footnote if that would be the first footnote on this page for the given function name.

How do I do this?

Comment: First footnote on the page, or first mention of the footnote? ...just to be clear. The former is more difficult than the latter.

Comment: Do you really want several footnotes that basically say the same thing?

Comment: Yes, although I misspoke -- once per chapter, not once per page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution makes sure that the `\cname` macro keeps track of the labels that have been used by storing them into a buffer -- that gets emptied when the page gets shipped out to make the feature work pagewise. If the current label, i.e. the second argument of `\cname` is alredy present in the buffer we know that no footnote should be produced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyshi}

\makeatletter
\def\cfunc@buffer{}
\def\check@buffer#1#2{\ifx#1#2\@tempswafalse\fi}
\newcommand{\cfunc}[2]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \edef\@tempa{#2}%
  \@for\lbl:=\cfunc@buffer\do{\check@buffer\lbl\@tempa}%
  \texttt{#2}%
  \if@tempswa\footnote{See \texttt{man #1 #2}.}\fi
  \index{#2}%
  \xdef\cfunc@buffer{#2,\cfunc@buffer}%
}
\EveryShipout{\global\let\cfunc@buffer\@empty}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The \cfunc{3}{malloc} function allocates memory...

The \cfunc{3}{malloc} function allocates more memory...

The \cfunc{3}{foo} function doesn't even exist...

\clearpage

The \cfunc{3}{malloc} function allocates some memory again...
\end{document}
```

[image: example_rendered]

## Addendum

Here come a few details on the implementation:

First a macro is initialized that will serve as a storage for the labels alredy used with the `\cname` macro. And an auxiliary macro is defined.

```
\def\cfunc@buffer{}
\def\check@buffer#1#2{\ifx#1#2\@tempswafalse\fi}
```

Then the definition of `\cname` is set up by first leting a switch, i.e. `\if@tempswa` (that is predefined in the LaTeX kernel) to 'true' and storing the current label into the (also predefined storage-)macro `\@tempa`.

```
\newcommand{\cfunc}[2]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \edef\@tempa{#2}%
```

Now we check if the current label is alredy present in the buffer.

```
  \@for\lbl:=\cfunc@buffer\do{\check@buffer\lbl\@tempa}%
```

If it was, the switch `\if@tempswa` is set to 'false' (see the definition of `\check@buffer`). Now, based on this we can output the information as planned -- the footnote will only appear if the current label wasn't in the stored list.

```
  \texttt{#2}%
  \if@tempswa\footnote{See \texttt{man #1 #2}.}\fi
  \index{#2}%
```

Last, but *really* not least the current label gets written into the storage:

```
  \xdef\cfunc@buffer{#2,\cfunc@buffer}%
}
```

*Note*. If you need to operate on some other layer than the pages, e.g. on the `\section`s you need to refresh the buffer by hooking into the `\section` macro like

```
\let\ltx@section\section
\renewcommand\section{\let\cfunc@buffer\@empty\ltx@section}
```

#### Complete test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\cfunc@buffer{}
\def\check@buffer#1#2{\ifx#1#2\@tempswafalse\fi}
\newcommand{\cfunc}[2]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \edef\@tempa{#2}%
  \@for\lbl:=\cfunc@buffer\do{\check@buffer\lbl\@tempa}%
  \texttt{#2}%
  \if@tempswa\footnote{See \texttt{man #1 #2}.}\fi
  \index{#2}%
  \xdef\cfunc@buffer{#2,\cfunc@buffer}%
}
\let\ltx@section\section
\renewcommand\section{\let\cfunc@buffer\@empty\ltx@section}
\makeatother

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{C functions}

The \cfunc{3}{malloc} function allocates memory...

The \cfunc{3}{malloc} function allocates more memory...

The \cfunc{3}{foo} function doesn't even exist...

\section{more C functions}

The \cfunc{3}{malloc} function allocates some memory again...
\end{document}
```

[image: addendum_rendered]

Comment: Thank you! This will take me while to understand. Why do you have comment marks at the end of some lines? I see this a lot.

Comment: Also, how would I adjust this to reset the counters every chapter, say, or section instead of every page? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @spraff -- The comment marks are there to make sure that there isn't any undesired white space. (Just cancel them for a try and you will see.)

Comment: @spraff -- To reset the buffer every page I used the `\EveryShipout` hook provided by the `everyshi` package. Hence for making that the feature work chapter or sectionwise you need to hook into those commands, e.g. `\EverySection{\global\let\cfunc@buffer\@empty}` instead of `\EveryShipout...`; only: there is no `\EverySection` command (at least not in standard LaTeX), but it's not too hard to do this by hand in this case. I'll add an addendum to my answer. Anyways, if you find it helpful you might consider upvoting and accpeting the answer. This is the usual way to say "thanks" here.

Comment: @spraff -- I added a few notes on the implementation in the addendum.

Comment: Nice, but I'm not sure this really works if a term happens to be in a paragraph which is split across pages and it ends up in the next page, because the check is performed before the list is cleared.

Comment: @egreg -- thanks! and dayum: the old problem regarding (La)TeXs page building routine. At this point I don't see a quick and intelligent fix to the algorithm. Maybe I need a starred version of the command that forces the switch to be false regardless of the test result(?) -- and the user would have to double check. But honestly I don't know if thats viable.

Comment: To test it, remove the blank lines around `\clearpage` and change it into `\pagebreak\hfill\linebreak`.

Comment: The "document" `\lipsum[1]\par\lipsum[1]\par\lipsum[1]\par\lipsum[2]\par
Lorem ipsum dolor \cfunc{3}{malloc} sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore \cfunc{3}{malloc} et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.` (assuming the `article` class with nothing else) will produce the same misbehaviour.

Comment: @egreg -- Do you know if TeX keeps track of paragraphs that are broken over a page? So, at least there is the hope to create some kind of warning.

Comment: @egreg -- Anyways, by hooking into anything else than the page building routine, e.g. the sectioning level one should be rather safe, right? (At least I don't see anything really concering at the moment, which doesn't have to mean that much maybe... ;)

Comment: @Ruben This is similar to, but more complicated than, the problem of per page footnote numbers. The big difference is that a footnote could change the page break, with consequences you can imagine. But this is useless, as the OP has specified once per chapter.